# remove a newline befor a specific character in a txt file perl

Tags: perl

i have a problem i have a txt file that has several lines with a three line pattern that for some reason is unpastable so i have to describe it. first line starts looks like this ">@1M1U7:00204:00340" can have any number after the : but have a fixed number of characters. The next line look like this "_F_48_32.0416666667" and can have any number after the last underscore and can be of different legths. The last lien in the pattern is a DNA sequence. what i want is to join the two first lines together.

I want a script in perl that can fix this for me

Comment: Try `xxd file` or `od file` and paste the output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just `chomp` every first line of the three-line group:

```
perl -pe 'chomp if 1 == $. % 3' < input > output
```

Comment: thank you so much i make problems harder than they are